# How to write to a text file from 2 non connected ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file, text, file-writing

I'm trying to use a VBA code to write a range of data from my spreadsheet into a txt file that I will import into a statistical program such as STATA.

The first column of the range I want to write is, for example, "A1:A25".
The second column will be user selected range, for example, "C1:C25"

The code I have tried so far will only work if the two columns are next to each other (columns A and B). If they are not connected (columns A and C) then the file writes both column A and column C into one long column of data into the txt file instead of two columns.

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
Sub testwrite()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim newRng As Range
path = ActiveWorkbook.path

    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A25")
    Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select a column of data", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    Set rng = Union(rng1, rng2)
    
    Dim check As String
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim output As String
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output = output & "," & c.Value
        Next c
        output = output & vbNewLine
    Next r
    Open path & "\text_data3.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Should you be adding any text qualifier to the output CSV fields or is this strictly numeric output or text string that will NEVER contain a comma within itself?

Comment: Are the column header labels in A1:A25 and you are trying to transpose the values from rows-to-columns or are the column header labels in A1:C1 and you simply want to dump the output row-by-row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is column A & C

```
A  |  C
=======
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

and the output you are looking for is

```
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

You do not want to use union, you will loop through one range then the other. You can just loop through the ranges for your desired output.

```
Sub testwrite()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim newRng As Range
Dim Path As String
Dim r As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim rows As Integer

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A25")
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select a column of data", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
rows = rng1.Count
Dim output As String

For i = 1 To rows Step 1
    output = output & rng1.rows(i).Value & "," & rng2.rows(i).Value & vbCrLf
Next i

Open Path & "\text_data3.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. Quick follow-up, is there a way to augment the inputbox command so that the user selects only the first cell in the column (for example "C1") and then the range is set to be all the available data in column C?

Comment: That sounds like a whole new question :)

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your code. Everything is similar, but your chosen ranges are converted to arrays.

```
Sub testwrite()
Dim ar1 As Variant
Dim ar2 As Variant
Dim Path As String
Dim i As Long 'counter
Dim output As String
    Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ar1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A25").Value
    ar2 = Application.InputBox("Select a column of data", _
        "Obtain Array Data", Type:=64)

    For i = 1 To UBound(ar1, 1)
        output = output & "," & ar1(i, 1) & "," & ar2(i, 1) & vbNewLine
    Next

    Open Path & "\text_data3.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Better done via arrays as you did (+1). Given `ouput ` is the long string better concatenate with  `output = output & ("," & ar1(i, 1) & "," & ar2(i, 1) & vbNewLine)` so the long string is only concatenated once.

Comment: @brettdj Thanks for the valuable remark! Does it help with performance or is less prone to error?

Comment: Performance. Better to concatenation a long string once in an operation rather than repeatedly